# Nested Optional.get generates warning when checked and chained in orElse()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, option-type

I've just stumbled upon a warning generated by IntelliJ and I'm wondering, do I miss something or is IntelliJ just ignoring the right side of the following or clause?

Example Code:

```
  Random random = new Random();
  public void test(){
    Optional<String> a = Optional.ofNullable(random.nextInt(10)>5?"something":null);
    Optional<String> b = Optional.ofNullable(random.nextInt(10)>5?"something":null);
    if(a.isPresent() || b.isPresent()){
      log.info(a.orElse(b.get()));
      //Some more stuff that is depends on a or b being present
    }
  }
```

The warning `'Optional.get()' without 'isPresent()' check`  is shown on the `b.get()`.
I get that the or is evaluated from left to right in a lazy way but I would assume that either `a` or `b` has to have a value present as it's checked explicitly in the if.

Is that an error in IntelliJ's static code analysis?

Comment: Note that `b.get()` will be evaluated regardless of `b.isPresent()` being true. You may want `a.orElseGet(b::get)`, since this will not evaluate `b.get()` unless `a` is not present.

Comment: @Rogue `b.get()` gets executed iff `a.isPresent()` is false. And in that case `b.isPresent()` must be true since it is an OR condition

Comment: @ArunGowda you will still evaluate `b.get()` when calling `#orElse`, as it will need to be evaluated to be passed as a parameter to `#orElse`. Using `#orElseGet` will accept a `Supplier<T>`, which will only be evaluated in the case you specified.

Comment: I would argue using `ifPresent` and `get` is a code smell, because used like this kind of defeats the use of `Optional` in the first place. `Optional` provides chainable methods over values that can exist or not, and they check if the value is present, if you intend to get the value from it. `orElse` does an internal check for `null`, which is exactly what `isPresent` does, therefore you can chain operations like this: `log.info(a.orElse(b.orElse("a and be are null")));`

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip In my given example you're absolutely right. I've ommited some more logic that depends on the isPresent. I will edit my post so it will be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes-ish. `||` short-circuits but `orElse` doesn't, so `b.get` still runs and raises an exception if `b` is absent, even if `a` is present. That's why Java provides [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-), which takes a `Supplier` (i.e. a zero-argument function) to be called if we actually *need* to run the 'else' part.

```
log.info(a.orElseGet(() -> b.get()));
```

Now, I don't have IntelliJ available on this computer right now, but I suspect it will still complain. The static analysis engine (probably) doesn't understand the interaction between `orElseGet` and `||`. Generally, when I encounter situations like this, I factor the offending code out into a separate function.

```
void onFirst<T>(Optional<T> first, Optional<T> second, Consumer<T> consumer) {
  if (first.isPresent()) {
    consumer.accept(first.get());
  } else if (second.isPresent()) {
    consumer.accept(second.get());
  }
}

// Then call as
onFirst(a, b, (value) -> log.info(value));
```

A bit more wordy, but it passes static analysis muster. And the extra wordiness is off in a separate helper function that can be reused.

Comment: That's it I didn't think of the resolution of the nested methods here. Replacing it with the `orElseGet` variant solved the warning.

Comment: Oh, that's impressive. I'm pleasantly surprised IntelliJ figured that interaction out. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

> I get that the or is evaluated from left to right in a lazy way

Yes, which means that if `a.isPresent()` returns true, `b.isPresent()` won't be evaluated and the condition will be true regardless. At which point your `b.get()` will throw an exception if `b.isPresent()` is false.

Since you're using `a.orElse` further down, you can simply check whether `b.isPresent()`, since `orElse` won't throw an exception if `a` is empty. So

```
if(b.isPresent()){
  log.info(a.orElse(b.get()));
}
```

shouldn't give a warning.

(I'm assuming this is a toy example, so I won't comment further on the abuse of `Optional` that is going on here)

Comment: But there are only 4 paths to be taken here. Either none is present (not interesting in this example), `a` is present, `b` is present or both are present. If `a` is present `b.get()` would never be called. If `b` is present but not `a` then the resolution of `a.orElse(...)` would lead to `b.get()` be called.

And yes it's a dumbed down example from some code I have in my application. The check for `a.isPresent()` and `b.isPresent()` is actually needed as some more things should happen when either has a value. Just having `b.isPresent()` would not work correctly here.

Comment: *"If a is present `b.get()` would never be called."*  `b.get()` will be evaluated regardless. If you don't want it evaluated you have to use `orElseGet`: `log.info(a.orElseGet(() -> b.get()))`